# Using ssl with werkzeug not working with handle_request method

Tags: python, windows, ssl, https, werkzeug

So I am trying to handle a single request and close the server using the handle_request method on the BaseWSGIServer from the werkzeug module but it doesn't seem to work. The program starts and ends with no errors in the terminal, however in the browser, I get an error saying I cannot connect to the server because it took too long to respond.

Code producing problem

```
from threading import Thread
from werkzeug.serving import make_server
from werkzeug import Request, Response

def create_server():
    @Request.application
    def callback(request):
        print("callback called")
        return Response("Successfull", 200)

    return make_server("localhost", 4000, callback, ssl_context="adhoc")

server = create_server()
Thread(target=server.handle_request).start()
```

[Response in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6R7Q.jpg)

I tried using the serve_forever method and it worked. Don't know why this doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.